# In IBAction: "arguments passed to call that takes no arguments"

Tags: ios, animation, closures, ibaction, swift2

[image]

From what I've seen, the best way to resolve this error:

> arguments passed to call that takes no arguments

will be to use

```
do {try ...} and catch {...}
```

However, it seems impossible to implement it in this code!

```
@IBAction func onTapButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    btnFromNib.animate(1, completion: { () -> () in

        var myTabbarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController("myTabbarController") as! UITabBarController
        var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = myTabbarController

        myTabbarController.transitioningDelegate = self

        self.presentViewController(myTabbarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })

}
```

Comment: That worked ... thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to instantiate a view controller *with an identifier parameter*, but you're not using the right method for this.

You should use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` instead of `instantiateInitialViewController`.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:

> Instantiates and returns the view controller with the specified identifier.
>
> You use this method to create view controller objects that you want to manipulate and present programmatically in your application. Before you can use this method to retrieve a view controller, you must explicitly tag it with an appropriate identifier string in Interface Builder.
>
> This method creates a new instance of the specified view controller each time you call it.

Comment: @ Eric D. Although that worked, i get this morning ad the Debug area: whose view is not in the window hierarchy!     Any idea?

Comment: No idea, sorry. It looks like it's a different issue.